# ADODB connection with Excel recordset

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to retire the data and update the same in worksheet via SQL query. I am getting the result on change in array 'i' but there is no result for change in array 'j' and 'k'.
Not sure as to what went wrong. All the field names are correct.

I am not sure if I am not getting result because of below coding.

```
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, 3, 1
```

***Complete coding***

```
Dim ReturnArray
Dim Conn As New adodb.Connection
Dim mrs As New adodb.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
Dim sSQLSting As String

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

`enter code here`sconnect ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & DBPath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"

```
For i = 0 To com1 - 1
    For j = 0 To com2 - 1
        For k = 0 To com3 - 1
            Conn.Open sconnect
            sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [DataSheet$] where [Vertical]= '" & Sheets(1).ComboBox1.List(i) & "' and [Activities]= '" & Sheets(1).ComboBox3.List(k) & "'"
            mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, 3, 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(za, 4).Value = mrs.RecordCount
            za = za + 1
            mrs.Close
            Conn.Close
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: How is this related to access vba? Why are you using the `MSDASQL.1` provider when you want to open Excel files?

Comment: I have changed coding to sconnect ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & DBPath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";" but still facing same issue.